# Android Application for Kids

Tags: java, android, parental-control

I'm Developing Android Application for Parental Controlling, so I want to disable home and back button. Because kids are unpredictable, their can push home button or back button and so on. Than i want to disable sliding notification bar. (Because notification bar can change device configuration and setting)

I'm planning to create Android Application which is similar to the [Samsung Kids Mode-Parental Control](http://gs5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/enable-kids-mode-your-galaxy-s5-0154991/).

Is possible to create application like Samsung Kids Mode? Can you give some link/article or even example program to me?

I Have tried this :

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {

  this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
  super.onAttachedToWindow();

}
```

but it not handle home button, the Home button still working.

Thanks in advance to everyone for taking time to read this, hoping a positive solution.

Comment: Please give your reason why this question must be vote down.

Comment: I think it was voted down because you didnt show any example code you have written youself to try and solve the problem

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. Can it vote up again? Because i think it useful for another in next time.

Comment: You might want to explain how you are going to be different than guest mode/restricted profile https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865944?hl=en

Comment: It seems like you need to do a bit more research before posting questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of anyway to override the home button. Im not sure that it can be done. You can override the back button like so.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //do nothing, important dont call super.onBackPressed
}
```

Another this you can do is set the app to immersive mode to reduce the chance of accidently exiting the app

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 1):

Extended from Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

can be used to override back button. Be sure to remove `super.onBackPressed()`.